# Копировать проект в папку с номером версии проекта

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, msbuild

Хочется использовать версионность приложения как нынче у браузеров - в подпапках лежат целиком старые и новые версии и какую запускать решает лишь простой лаунчер:

[image: Картинка с содержимым в папке браузера]

Вопрос - можно ли в проекте на событиях билда(до сборки, после сборки, не важно по идее) как то указать копирование не в конкретную подпапку, а в ту, которая соответствует текущей версии проекта?
Интересуют реализации как без сторонних утилит, так и с ними, если других вариантов нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Удалось найти решение на [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19371257/3768545).

Выгружаем проект лаунчера и пишем в него:

```
  <Target Name="PostBuildMacros">
    <GetAssemblyIdentity AssemblyFiles="$(TargetPath)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Assemblies" ItemName="Targets" />
    </GetAssemblyIdentity>
    <ItemGroup>
      <VersionNumber Include="@(Targets->'%(Version)')"/>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <PostBuildEventDependsOn>
      $(PostBuildEventDependsOn);
      PostBuildMacros;
    </PostBuildEventDependsOn>
    <PostBuildEvent>
      md "$(TargetDir)\@(VersionNumber)"
      xcopy /y /r /e "$(ProjectDir)\..\Core\bin\$(ConfigurationName)" "$(TargetDir)\@(VersionNumber)"</PostBuildEvent>
```

Насколько понимаю, решение получилось немного сборку, ведь версия берется от самого лаунчера. Для меня это не проблема, т.к. использую одну версию на всё решение.

Comment: У MSBuild'а есть встроенные Task'и, которые позволяют отказаться от вызова md, xcopy.